# How to create a gif animation that plays only once

Tags: go, gif, animated-gif

I am trying to generate an animated gif that plays the frames only once.

When I set LoopCount to 1, it plays the frames twice. When I set LoopCount to 0 or -1, it loops infinitely.

```
img := image.(*image.Paletted)

outGif := &gif.GIF{}
outGif.LoopCount = 0
outGif.Image = append(outGif.Image, img)
outGif.Delay = append(outGif.Delay, 10)

f, err := os.Create("/tmp/test.gif")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()

gif.EncodeAll(f, outGif)
```

How to I make sure it only plays the frames once?

Comment: When I try this `0` loops forever, and `1` and `2` work exactly as expected, with `1` playing the animation exactly once?

Comment: Hmm... What do you use to play the gif? I use chrome. Maybe that is playing it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers interpret differently the loop counter. For a single loop gif, Chrome is looping twice while Firefox is playing the animation exactly once.

See this issue of [GifCreator - Unable to create non loop GIF image](https://github.com/Sybio/GifCreator/issues/4#issuecomment-41282288).